# Local copy of JavaScript code not working when it's online demo is

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JavaScript using MDN web docs. In that, the following piece of code is given -

```js
function CreateParagraph() {
  var para = document.createElement('p');
  para.textContent = 'You clicked the button!';
  document.body.appendChild(para);

  var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', createParagraph);
  }
}
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
```

The [online demo](https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/javascript/introduction-to-js-1/what-is-js/apply-javascript-internal.html) of this code works but when I made a local copy, that is not working. What exactly is wrong here?

Comment: The `for` needs to go *outside* the `CreateParagraph()` function. Voting to close as a typo

Comment: Please define *not working*. Is your function not getting called? Is it not appending elements? or anything else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have fun on your Javascript journey. MDN is a good place to start.

If you look at the example code again. Pay close attention to opening and closing braces `{}`. In your local example you've put all the code inside your function.

This is the example from MDN. See how it differs from yours?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Apply JavaScript example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button>Click me</button>

    <script>
      function createParagraph() {
        var para = document.createElement('p');
        para.textContent = 'You clicked the button!';
        document.body.appendChild(para);
      }

      var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

      for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length ; i++) {
        buttons[i].addEventListener('click', createParagraph);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It also differs for the function name. It's capitalized in the OP's code while it shouldn't

Comment: @Lex Wow. That was incredibly foolish of me. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @sindhugauri it still happens to the best developers regularly. Mistakes will happen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `CreateParagraph()` in the local code

Your online working code is

```
  function createParagraph() {
    var para = document.createElement('p');
    para.textContent = 'You clicked the button!';
    document.body.appendChild(para);
  }
```

// see the  change here- different from your local function

```
  var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
  for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length ; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', createParagraph);
  }
```

The function is not getting binded to any element. In your working code you first created the function and then using for-loop you added event listener to all button elements in the page

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to do,

```js
function CreateParagraph() {
          var para = document.createElement('p');
          para.textContent = 'You clicked the button!';
          document.body.appendChild(para);

          
      }
      var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

          for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length ; i++) {
            buttons[i].addEventListener('click', CreateParagraph);
          }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Apply JavaScript example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button>Click me</button>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

2 changes and it worked for me.

- You have misplaced the curly braces. The for loop should be outside
  function CreateParagraph
- Note the case when calling CreateParagraph function. The name of the function during its definition and invocation should be in the same case.

The below code would work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Apply JavaScript example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button>Click me</button>

      <script>
      function CreateParagraph() {
          var para = document.createElement('p');
          para.textContent = 'You clicked the button!';
          document.body.appendChild(para);
        }
          var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

          for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length ; i++) {
            buttons[i].addEventListener('click', CreateParagraph);
          }

      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```